# round variable in bash without printing it to stdout

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a script that recognizes if someone is streaming data from my samba server (i.e. music is playing - or not). For that, I've come up with a script like this:

```
$ cat /home/ron/scripts/keepup.sh
#!/bin/bash

exec=`nethogs -t -c 1| awk '/smbd/ {print $2}'`

sent=$exec

echo "result: "$sent
sent="($sent+0.5)/1" | bc
echo "rounded: "$sent
if [[ $sent -gt 0 ]]
then 
    echo "music is playing"
else
    echo "quiet"
fi
```

but I get:

```
Waiting for first packet to arrive (see sourceforge.net bug 1019381)
result: 6.73438
rounded: 6.73438
/home/ron/scripts/keepup.sh: line 10: [[: 6.73438: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".73438")
quiet
```

While it should obviously compute the result "6.73438" to true. It seems like my rounding isn't working properly. I've googled around but only found answers using echo or printf but that's npt what I need as I want to feed the rounded result into the if condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
sent="($sent+0.5)/1" | bc
```

You need:

```
sent=$(bc <<< "($sent+0.5)/1")
```

Or:

```
sent=$(echo "($sent+0.5)/1" | bc)
```

Answer (score 1):

`bc` is not making any rounding. Consider those tests:

```
$ a="17.928671"; a=$(bc -l <<<"scale=3; $a/1");echo "$a"
17.928

$ a="17.928671"; a=$(printf '%.3f\n' "$a");echo "$a"
17.929
```

About `bc` consider that `scale` option can be used to adjust the number of decimal digits (scale=3), but in order this `scale=3` to be activated `bc` expects to receive a division.

As a result, if you need rounding i would suggest to use `printf`